# Log4Net adonet appender sometimes does not trace

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have a strange problem with log4net in a .net application (actual version 4.7.2).
I have activated multiple loggers with a class that extends AdoNetAppender (I've overriden only how to get the connection string) with a configuration like this:

```
  <appender name="MyTraceAppender" type="mytype, myassembly">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionStringName value="RootContext"/>
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES (values)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@paramname" />
      <dbType value="Int32" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{paramname}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
.....

  </appender>
```

Then, from the code I call the logger in this mode

```
ThreadContext.Properties["paramname"] = paramvalue;
            ....        
Logger.Info("");
```

I have noticed that a logger traces all requests, but another one seems to "lose" some logs on the database
First Logger traces only some params, while second logger traces significant bigger data (for example body requests)

Database connection is for a Azure SQL database. It seems that there are no errors from the logger, but probably does it be related from some concurrency problems? If yes, how can I handle that?

If I increment buffer size, can I have problems on memory management?

Comment: I’d advise turning on [internal logging](https://riptutorial.com/log4net/example/32057/enable-internal-debugging) as otherwise you won’t see any errors from log4net